# Text input unresponsive, not accepting text despite typing cursor appearing on mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that allows users to input exact time locations into their video player. It's a simple overlay that appears over a video frame. It works on YouTube videos (although I still have to deal with periodically "losing connection" with the tab), and does in fact appear over videos in the Spotify player, but I cannot enter text into the input.

To be more specific, the input appears and displays a typing cursor on mouseover. However, the input cannot be focused and the blinking cursor does not appear. No text will appear if I click on the input and begin typing. If I do submit the form, the video's time input will be set to 0 as I assume the default empty value would be 0 (so, 0 seconds into the video).

Additionally, if I modify the value tag directly within the DOM, submitting the form will function properly. The sole issue is that I cannot focus the input.

The input is *z-indexed* to the `top-most` and above the underlying div it's nested in. There are no changes made to the HTML when injected into the Spotify site, and no error messages in the console.

Previously, the overlay would not appear on top of the video. The issue came from Spotify requiring an id and class name for the HTML element in order to display.

Again, my cursor does in fact change on mouseover. Clicking on the input, however, does not focus the input and I cannot enter text into the input at all.

Code:

There is only one input, with the id `timeInput` and the styling `input_style`.

```
console.log("content.js");
let overlayVisibleBool = false;

// Function to handle overlay display
function toggleOverlay(overlayVisible) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    { command: "checkActiveTab" },
    function (response) {
      if (response && response.isValid) {
        const videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        const popup = document.getElementById("rr_overlay");

        if (videoElement && popup) {
          const videoRect = videoElement.getBoundingClientRect();

          overlayVisible = !overlayVisible;

          if (!overlayVisible) {
            console.log(videoRect);
            popup.style.display = "flex";
            popup.style.position = "absolute";
            popup.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
            popup.style.bottom = videoRect.bottom + "px";
            popup.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
            popup.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
            popup.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";

            popup.style.zIndex = 9999;

            popup.style.justifyContent = "center";
            popup.style.alignItems = "center";
            popup.style.flexDirection = "column";

            const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
            if (timeInput) {
              timeInput.focus();
            }
          } else {
            // Hide the overlay
            popup.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
}

window.onresize = function () {
  const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
  const videoRect = videoElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const popup = document.getElementById("rr_overlay");
  popup.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
  popup.style.bottom = videoRect.bottom + "px";
  popup.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
  popup.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
  popup.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";
};

let overlay_style = `
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  clear: both;
`;

let image_style = `
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
`;

let link_logo_style = `
  width: 12px;
  height: auto;
`;

let input_style = `
  border: 0px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
`;

let form_style = `
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

let button_style = `
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(255,27,0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,27,0,1) 0%, rgba(251,75,2,1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
`;

let link_button_style = `
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(255,27,0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,27,0,1) 0%, rgba(251,75,2,1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const rr_logo = chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/rrewind.svg");
const link_logo = chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/link.svg");
const overlay = **image attached**
const popupElement = document.createElement("div");
popupElement.id = "popup_container";
popupElement.className = "popup_container";
popupElement.innerHTML = overlay;
document.body.appendChild(popupElement);

console.log("Plugged in.");

const jumpForm = document.getElementById("jumpForm");

jumpForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submitting jump");
  manageTime(e);
});

function manageTime(e) {
  console.log(timeInput);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    { command: "checkActiveTab" },
    function (response) {
      if (response && response.isValid) {
        const action = e.submitter.value;
        console.log(action);
        if (action === "jump") {
          const timeInput = document
            .getElementById("timeInput")
            .value.split(":");
          console.log(timeInput);
          tl = timeInput.length;

          let hoursInput, minutesInput, secondsInput, totalSeconds;

          if (tl === 3) {
            hoursInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
            minutesInput = parseInt(timeInput[1], 10) || 0;
            secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[2], 10) || 0;
            totalSeconds = hoursInput * 3600 + minutesInput * 60 + secondsInput;
          } else if (tl === 2) {
            minutesInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
            secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[1], 10) || 0;
            totalSeconds = minutesInput * 60 + secondsInput;
          } else if (tl === 1) {
            secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
            totalSeconds = secondsInput;
          } else {
            return;
          }

          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            command: "jumpToTime",
            time: totalSeconds,
          });
          overlayVisibleBool = false;
          toggleOverlay(overlayVisibleBool);
        } else if (action === "link") {
          const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
          let totalSeconds = videoElement.currentTime;
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            command: "getLink",
            time: totalSeconds,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  // Check if CTRL + ` is pressed
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "`") {
    console.log("TOGGLE ACTIVATED!");
    overlayVisibleBool = !overlayVisibleBool;
    console.log("overlay: ", overlayVisibleBool);
    toggleOverlay(overlayVisibleBool);
  }
});
```

The injected HTML (couldn't attach the text):
[image: Code snippet.]

background.js:

```
function getActiveTabId(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    if (tabs && tabs.length > 0) {
      const tabId = tabs[0].id;
      callback(tabId);
    }
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.command === "checkActiveTab") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      const isValid = tabs && tabs.length > 0;
      sendResponse({ isValid: isValid });
    });
    return true; // Indicates that sendResponse will be called asynchronously
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (
  message,
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  getActiveTabId((tabId) => {
    if (message.command === "jumpToTime") {
      console.log("message sent: jumpToTime");
      chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
          target: { tabId: tabId },
          func: (time) => {
            const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
            if (videoElement) {
              console.log("total time: ", time);
              videoElement.currentTime = time;
            }
          },
          args: [message.time], // Pass the time parameter
        },
        (result) => {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(
              "Background script: Error executing script in content script:",
              chrome.runtime.lastError
            );
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Background script: Script executed successfully:",
              result
            );
          }
        }
      );
    } else if (message.command === "getLink") {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        func: (time) => {
          if (window.location.href.includes("youtube")) {
            const pageUrl = window.location.href
              .replace("www.", "")
              .replace("youtube.com", "youtu.be")
              .replace("watch?v=", "");
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(
              pageUrl + "?feature=shared&t=" + Math.ceil(time)
            );
          } else {
            const pageUrl = window.location.href;
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(pageUrl);
          }
        },
        args: [message.time],
      });
    }
  });
  return true;
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "RedbarRewind",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Give it a year.",
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/rrewind16.png",
      "48": "assets/rrewind48.png",
      "128": "assets/rrewind128.png"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "assets/rrewind.svg",
        "assets/redbarrewind.svg",
        "assets/link.svg"
      ],
      "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/rrewind16.png",
    "48": "assets/rrewind48.png",
    "128": "assets/rrewind128.png"
  }
}
```

The main problem, I'm assuming, lies with a hidden necessity in the HTML or styling that I'm missing. As I mentioned before, the parent div required a class and id in order to appear overlaid on the video, something I'd noticed in the CSS injected by the Spotify styling.

There is also no hint that the input is in any way disabled or readonly in the DOM. It might also be an issue with the CSP (Content Security Policy) although those error pop up in the console regardless of whether the addon is enabled or not. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting because I was able to get it working right away with your code ...

In any case, I changed a few things as I didn't have the images, etc.,
is it possible the Ctrl combination causes this, I used Ctrl+z, or maybe
you have a erroneous character in your content script injection ?

manifest.json

```
   {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "RedbarRewind",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Give it a year.",
      "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting"],
      "host_permissions": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"],
      "action": {
        "default_icon": {
          "128": "icon.png"
        }
      },
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": [
            "link.svg"
          ],
          "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*", "https://*.spotify.com/*"]
        }
      ],
      "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
      }
    }
```

background.js

```
function getActiveTabId(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    if (tabs && tabs.length > 0) {
      const tabId = tabs[0].id;
      callback(tabId);
    }
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.command === "checkActiveTab") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      const isValid = tabs && tabs.length > 0;
      sendResponse({ isValid: isValid });
    });
    return true; // Indicates that sendResponse will be called asynchronously
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (
  message,
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  getActiveTabId((tabId) => {
    if (message.command === "jumpToTime") {
      console.log("message sent: jumpToTime");
      chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
          target: { tabId: tabId },
          func: (time) => {
            const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
            if (videoElement) {
              console.log("total time: ", time);
              videoElement.currentTime = time;
            }
          },
          args: [message.time], // Pass the time parameter
        },
        (result) => {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(
              "Background script: Error executing script in content script:",
              chrome.runtime.lastError
            );
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Background script: Script executed successfully:",
              result
            );
          }
        }
      );
    } else if (message.command === "getLink") {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        func: (time) => {
          if (window.location.href.includes("youtube")) {
            const pageUrl = window.location.href
              .replace("www.", "")
              .replace("youtube.com", "youtu.be")
              .replace("watch?v=", "");
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(
              pageUrl + "?feature=shared&t=" + Math.ceil(time)
            );
          } else {
            const pageUrl = window.location.href;
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(pageUrl);
          }
        },
        args: [message.time],
      });
    }
  });
  return true;
});
```

content.js

```
    let overlayVisibleBool = false;
    
    // Function to handle overlay display
    function toggleOverlay(overlayVisible) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { command: "checkActiveTab" },
        function (response) {
          if (response && response.isValid) {
            const videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
            const popup = document.getElementById("rr_overlay");
    
            if (videoElement && popup) {
              const videoRect = videoElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    
              overlayVisible = !overlayVisible;
    
              if (!overlayVisible) {
                console.log(videoRect);
                popup.style.display = "flex";
                popup.style.position = "absolute";
                popup.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
                popup.style.bottom = videoRect.bottom + "px";
                popup.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
                popup.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
                popup.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";
    
                popup.style.zIndex = 9999;
    
                popup.style.justifyContent = "center";
                popup.style.alignItems = "center";
                popup.style.flexDirection = "column";
    
                const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
                if (timeInput) {
                  timeInput.focus();
                }
              } else {
                // Hide the overlay
                popup.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
    
    window.onresize = function () {
      const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
      const videoRect = videoElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const popup = document.getElementById("rr_overlay");
      popup.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
      popup.style.bottom = videoRect.bottom + "px";
      popup.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
      popup.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
      popup.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";
    };
    
    let overlay_style = `
      display: none; 
      position: fixed; 
      top: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      clear: both;
    `;
    
    let image_style = `
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: -50px;
      margin-bottom: -15px;
    `;
    
    let link_logo_style = `
      width: 12px;
      height: auto;
    `;
    
    let input_style = `
      border: 0px solid;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: auto;
      outline: none;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      z-index: 99999 !important;
      clear: both;
      position: relative;
    `;
    
    let form_style = `
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    `;
    
    let button_style = `
      width: 100px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      background: rgb(255,27,0);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,27,0,1) 0%, rgba(251,75,2,1) 100%);
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: white;
    `;
    
    let link_button_style = `
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      background: rgb(255,27,0);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,27,0,1) 0%, rgba(251,75,2,1) 100%);
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    `;

    const overlay = `
    <div id="rr_overlay" style="${overlay_style}">
    <form style="${form_style}" id="jumpForm">
    <input style="${input_style}" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="timeInput" class="timeInput" name="timeInput" placeholder="00:00:00">
    <button style="${button_style}" type="submit" value="jump" name="action">Go</button>
    <button style="${link_button_style}" type="submit" value="link" name="link">RR</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    `;

    const popupElement = document.createElement("div");
    popupElement.id = "popup_container";
    popupElement.className = "popup_container";
    popupElement.innerHTML = overlay;
    document.body.appendChild(popupElement);
    
    console.log("Plugged in.");
    
    const jumpForm = document.getElementById("jumpForm");
    
    jumpForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("submitting jump");
      manageTime(e);
    });
    
    function manageTime(e) {
      console.log(timeInput);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { command: "checkActiveTab" },
        function (response) {
          if (response && response.isValid) {
            const action = e.submitter.value;
            console.log(action);
            if (action === "jump") {
              const timeInput = document
                .getElementById("timeInput")
                .value.split(":");
              console.log(timeInput);
              tl = timeInput.length;
    
              let hoursInput, minutesInput, secondsInput, totalSeconds;
    
              if (tl === 3) {
                hoursInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
                minutesInput = parseInt(timeInput[1], 10) || 0;
                secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[2], 10) || 0;
                totalSeconds = hoursInput * 3600 + minutesInput * 60 + secondsInput;
              } else if (tl === 2) {
                minutesInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
                secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[1], 10) || 0;
                totalSeconds = minutesInput * 60 + secondsInput;
              } else if (tl === 1) {
                secondsInput = parseInt(timeInput[0], 10) || 0;
                totalSeconds = secondsInput;
              } else {
                return;
              }
    
              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                command: "jumpToTime",
                time: totalSeconds,
              });
              overlayVisibleBool = false;
              toggleOverlay(overlayVisibleBool);
            } else if (action === "link") {
              const videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
              let totalSeconds = videoElement.currentTime;
              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                command: "getLink",
                time: totalSeconds,
              });
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
      // Check if CTRL + ` is pressed
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "z") {
        console.log("TOGGLE ACTIVATED!");
        overlayVisibleBool = !overlayVisibleBool;
        console.log("overlay: ", overlayVisibleBool);
        toggleOverlay(overlayVisibleBool);
      }
    });
```

PS.

Maybe you can consider using type="time" instead of type="text" ...

```
<form>
  <label for="pickTime">time: </label>
  <input type="time" id="pickTime" />
</form>
```

UPDATE:

Add the following to the end of the content.js script:

```
document.addEventListener("focusin", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

This will prevent document.onfocusin from stealing the focus on spotify ...
I have not tested extensively what functionality this might break on spotify's website, but it seems to work :)

*If you go into developer mode, and event listeners on *html* element you will notice a focusin added by vendor~web-player.18951c83.js and this is what causes the issues with the textbox.

Comment: I appreciate the response! Something being wrong on my end is definitely a possibility. Although, given that I hardly use Spotify, I doubted another extension was the issue.

Comment: Did you try youtube.com?, I tried it on that site ...

Comment: Yes, Youtube works. My question regarded the Spotify video player. The closest I can get to simulating the issue is enabling readonly on my input. Except, there is no indication that any JS is affecting the DOM element.

Comment: I didn't know Spotify had a video player, how do I access it to test ...

Comment: Thank you for volunteering to test! Here's a link to a video podcast, although you can just search for video podcasts on Spotify and play on the page, the video will appear. https://open.spotify.com/episode/2ErM75r4hgeeyVpfnZqOEa

Might have something to do with the asynchronous loading of the video on the page.

Comment: I see what you mean, I traced it down to a focusin event stealing the focus ..
See my updated answer response!

Comment: FOCUSIN! I tried checking if any events were affecting the element but my dev tools weren't picking up anything on the el. Didn't think to check root. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as losing connection with background I assume Chrome removes the background page, you could try something like this from background.js:

```
// Keep Alive
var createOffscreen = async function()
{
    try { await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({ url:chrome.runtime.getURL("offscreen.html"), reasons:["BLOBS"], justification:"Keep service worker alive" }); } catch(e) {}
}

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() { setTimeout(function() { createOffscreen(); }, 5000); });
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() { setTimeout(function() { createOffscreen(); }, 5000); });
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) { if (message.keepalive) console.log("OK"); });
```

offscreen.js:

```
setInterval(function () { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({keepalive:"Hi"}); }, 10000);
```

Also add an "offscreen" permission to manifest.json, and offscreen.html just includes the offscreen.js file. This way the background will stay loaded all the time, just like in manifest v2 ...

Comment: My current fix involves simply checking for a possible runtime id (chrome.runtime?.id) before performing methods like sendMessage. From what I understand, this error is mostly due to chrome losing track of the service worker on timeout or accessing different links. So it should work *in theory*, I'm testing it out. Thank you!